# How to use Java-specific functions in previous api levels?

Tags: java, android, api

Some java specific libraries asks for android min API 26. For example Base64.getUrlEncoder() asks for android min API 26. How can I use these java properties in previous api levels? I tried to increase compile java options to latest java version but still I'm not able to use in previous api levels. So is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't use those APIs below the stated minSDK.

Some APIs are cloned in the Support Library. `Base64.getUrlEncoder()` is not.

However you could use the [Android Base64](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) version which is available since API 8.